# NetApp SVM backups

Tags: netapp

does an NetApp SVM allow you to perform a backup of a remote server, something like a snapshot without having to mount for example an FNS volume from that SVM to the target server ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Are you trying to make a backup copy of your Netapp data, or use Netapp to make a backup copy of a server?

Comment: @Basil Thank you. Yes, I'm basically looking at FW traffic that is coming from an NetApp SVM towards one of our servers over udp/111 and some high range udp port 60856 and I'm wondering what traffic this could be. I also don't see the traffic from the target back to the SVM but I would expect it to be in the FW logs. I hope it is more clear now :)